# Change TextView value in a Fragment Class using Seekbar

Tags: java, android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I am using a Seekbar library so when I drag the seeker, I expect the textview to be updated with the value from the seeker but unfortunately my app crashes. I get an error that says, "resource not found on the TextView".
The code is below:

```
RangeSeekBar seekBar1;
seekBar1 = (RangeSeekBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

seekBar1.setValue(10);
seekBar1.setOnRangeChangedListener(new RangeSeekBar.OnRangeChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRangeChanged(RangeSeekBar view, float min, float max, boolean isFromUser) {
            seekBar1.setProgressDescription((int)min+"%");
            TextView txtAmount;
            txtAmount = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtAmount);
            txtAmount.setText((int) min);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:** You can't set int to the TextView like that, try this instead:

```
txtAmount.setText(Float.toString(min));
```

The overload you were using would look for a string resource identifier, that doesn't exist in this case. Here's the [correct one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)) that takes a CharSequence as an argument ([string is a CharSequence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)).

---

**Nice to know:** If you're now left wondering how an int can be an argument to setText, it's quite simple. In your app, you can have a `strings.xml` file that defines a set of resources strings to be used in the application:

```
<resources>
    <string name="test">This is a test</string>
</resources>
```

With that defined, you can show the text on your TextView like this:

```
txtAmount.setText(R.string.test);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an integer into setText, android expects the value to be a resource. The system is trying to find a resource who's id is equal to min. You need to convert min to a string.

So to get it working change `txtAmount.setText((int) min);` to `txtAmount.setText(String.valueOf(min));`